# Is there any way to stop current task from AsycTask and set new task priority high and run that first?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have multiple tasks in queue. On any event, I want to start new `AsyncTask` with high priority and stop current one then execute others.Is that possible?

Comment: [A google search revealed](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=asynctask%20cancel): call Cancel() method of AsyncTask from where you want to stop the execution, may be based on the button click. asyncTask.cancel( true ); 2. Now you have to check whether the AsyncTask is cancelled or not by using isCancelled method inside the doInBackground method

Comment: i have multiple task running in parallel with executeOnExecutor.

Answer (score -1):

For each task have one variable as priority. Set the priority at run-time and depending on that variable decide whether to cancel or start the thread.